# Arduino onboard LED pin number as a constant

Tags: led, arduino-ide, arduino-due

To use the onboard LED on an Arduino one usually has to know the pin number (13 in most cases), but is there a constant in the Arduino IDE one can use as well?

So is it possible to use something like `int LED = ONBOARDLED;` instead of using `int LED = 13;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `#define LED_BUILTIN 13`

([source](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/435fc323e0ab3b03bc5835e5309b5022bf57388a/hardware/arduino/sam/variants/arduino_due_x/variant.h#L97))

Answer (score 4):

Try `LED_BUILTIN`:

```
pins_arduino.h:static const uint8_t LED_BUILTIN = 13;
```